# Customize language for FQL response

Tags: facebook, internationalization, facebook-fql

Is there a way to get the FQL results in different languages?

Right now, [FQL's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Query_Language) response is returned in English. Can I customize the language to get response in some other language?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `?locale=en_GB` or whatever you like, for example,

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/fql?locale=de_DE&q=SELECT relationship_status FROM user WHERE uid =me()&access_token=...
```

would show the current user's relationship status in German. You can try this out with the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Flocale%3Dde_DE%26q%3DSELECT%20relationship_status%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%3Dme%28%29).